# IntelliJ using too much memory

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Using Intellij 14.1.5 on mac and keep getting this memory usage error?  What is the fix here? I have tried setting that xmx value from 1000mb to 40 to unknown (0).

Recently IntelliJ likes to lock up on me with the mac color wheel spinning wheel of death.

using a mac book pro with 16GB of memory.

[image]

Comment: Why not go crazy and set it to 8g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell by this screenshot. It's likely that the reason is not lack of memory, but something else. The best way to find that out is for you to file an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com and attach your log (Help | Show log...) there.